# Randomly pick X objects with distinct names

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

The following attempt:

```
Article.objects.filter(category__id="b5e20323-8cec-413a-b405-342b3809f9a4").distinct('title').order_by("?")
```

Gives me:

> ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

I tried to drop to raw SQL. So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT title from article WHERE category_id = '...') AS inner_distinct ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3
```

This works but I need to add an additional field to to the title. If I change my raw query to:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT title, id from article WHERE category_id = '...') AS inner_distinct ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3
```

All of a sudden the DISTINCT keyword has no effect.

How can I overcome this?

---

EDIT: Consider I have a table called Shapes. Here's the sample data:

```
ID                                      name
====================================    ========
2f3e9b34-0184-4e92-b205-88dac05b7cb0    Oval
b6382663-848a-4760-ad2a-3195977cf892    Line
e77a6a1a-7e99-4b00-97d3-df684e1bcc38    Line
ef7eb727-b4a8-43aa-b11f-1ddc5c0385fe    Triangle
```

The provided solutions `(SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, id from shapes AS inner_distinct ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3)` always return the following (in random order)

```
ID                                      name
====================================    ========
2f3e9b34-0184-4e92-b205-88dac05b7cb0    Oval
b6382663-848a-4760-ad2a-3195977cf892    Line
ef7eb727-b4a8-43aa-b11f-1ddc5c0385fe    Triangle
```

And never:

```
e77a6a1a-7e99-4b00-97d3-df684e1bcc38    Line
```

Instead of:

```
b6382663-848a-4760-ad2a-3195977cf892    Line
```

(both, although one at a time, should get picked some of the time!)

Comment: I would request to add sample data and expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this nice feature `distinct on` from Postgres.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (title) title, id from article WHERE category_id = '...') AS inner_distinct ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3
```

**EDIT:- Updated Query with latest sample data from OP.**

I took the `distinct on` to outer part and put `order by random()` to the inner which works as per expectation. Please check.

```
select distinct on (name) name,id 
  from (select name, id from shapes order by random()) as inner_distinct 
order by name limit 3
```

**Alternative to `DISTINCT ON` **

Using row_number() we could achieve what you want. I have tested with shapes but you can replace with `article` as per your need

```
select name,id 
  from (select name, id,row_number() over (partition by name order by random()) rn 
          from shapes) i 
where i.rn = 1
order by random()
limit 3
```

Comment: The problem with this is when I have multiple articles carrying the same title, it's always returning on of them. Not randomly picking from them.

Comment: @Adam Silver, I would request to provide some sample data which will help to look into the issue better.

Comment: Thanks - over (partition by...) worked (Alternative to DISTINCT ON doesn't work for me - always same rows).

Answer (score 1):

**Original Answer**

Well in this case, when you say select distinct title, id, you are telling it to select distinct using both 'title' and 'id'. So use distinct on like below:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (title) title, id from article WHERE category_id = '...') AS inner_distinct ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3
```

**Edited to provide randomness of distinct column**

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(title) title, id 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT * from article 
      WHERE category_id = '...' 
      ORDER BY RANDOM()
    ) inner_distinct
  ) inner_random 
ORDER BY RANDOM () 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: The problem with this is when I have multiple articles carrying the same title, it's always returning on of them. Not randomly picking from them.

Comment: This is almost what I need. The only problem is the rows are not ordered randomly. If I have 4 titles in my database, 2 of them carrying the same titles, one of the duplicate titles is getting excluded (what I want) but the titles are always coming in the same order.

Comment: The 3rd edit solution feels quite hacky, and I'm positive there's a better way it can be done, but it does get the job done.